# Page matching query does not exist - Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I have site on django. I pull it from repo, create database and do migrations by
python manage.py migrate

runserver without errors, but when I try open the page(localhost:8000), this is error 'Page matching query does not exist'

Comment: please share your codes, specially `urls.py`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you haven't configured the `urls.py` file correctly. I recommend you to install [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) and to do `python manage.py show_urls`. There you will see all the paths you have available.